# Gradle DSL method not found:android()

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Error:(1, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'

Possible causes:

The project 'MyApp1' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.

Gradle settings

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

Root/build.gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '21.1.1'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.shark.gpsapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

}

App/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.shark.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
             }
```

I coudln't open any of my old projects.Please do suggest a answer.
I got this error after android studio update.

Comment: Please post your `build.gradle` file(s). In a typical Android Studio project, there will be two of these, one in the project root directory, and one in the `app/` module directory off of the project root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call `android` until after you apply the android plugin `com.android.tools.build:gradle`.

The gradle build file uses a DSL based on Groovy, a Java-like dynamic language.  `android { ... }` is a call to a method named `android`, passing the block.  The message you are getting indicates that the method `android` has not been defined.  It is defined in the plugin.

Somehow, your root level `build.gradle` file is a near duplicate of your app level `build.gradle`.  It should not be so.

I suggest that you create a completely new project, using Android Studio, and copy it's root level `build.grade` file to the existing project.